# Linter Error: `assert(this.f.address == address(this));`

Tags: solidity

While learning solidity, I copy-pasted this code from: https://docs.soliditylang.org/en/v0.8.4/types.html

```
// SPDX-License-Identifier: GPL-3.0
pragma solidity >=0.6.4 <0.9.0;

contract Example {
    function f() public payable returns (bytes4) {
        assert(this.f.address == address(this));
        return this.f.selector;
    }

    function g() public {
        this.f{gas: 10, value: 800}();
    }
}
```

> Linter: Parse error: extraneous input ')' expecting ';' [undefined]

[image]

---

I'm using VSCode, with solidity version: `0.0.113`, and solc version: `0.8.4+commit.c7e474f2.Darwin.appleclang`

In Remix, I don't see this error (with same solc version):

[image]

What is this error and how can I fix it?

Answer (score 0):

Since your 'Example' contract works fine in Remix, it is likely that the error you see comes from other lines above `function f()` in your VSCode.

By the way, unless your smart contract has already some ether, you may have to add `payable` to function `g()`. Otherwise, you will get this error:

> Note: The called function should be payable if you send value and the
> value you send should be less than your current balance